# How to connect react native app to live URL server using socket.io for Chat application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Here is the code implemented for socket connection but it did not working.
I want to create chat messaging app in react native with realtime updates which uses backend of our web side server. I am trying to connect my app to socket io but its not working.

I have used `socket.IO-client` for react native:

```js
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.IO-client'

export default Class Socket extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    var Live_URL = "https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/"
    this.socket = SocketIOClient(Live_URL);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.socket.connect();
    this.socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log('connection.')
    });
  }
}
```

here is the server side code....

```
module.exports = function(app, httpServer) {

    var socketioJWT = require('socketio-jwt');
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(httpServer);
    var clients = [];
    var connectedClientSocketIds = []; //for store socket all opened ids.
    var clientsStatus = {};

    io.use(socketioJWT.authorize({
        secret: global.hzConfig.jwtPrivateKey,
        handshake: true
    }));

    //for store all ffmpeg converting process (user for kill running process)
    var runningFfmpegCommands = {};

    /**
     * @description Socket connection in when user going to online
     */
    io.sockets.on("connect", function(socket){
console.log(socket)
}
```

i am getting this kind of error in console.....

```
Error: server error
    at Socket.onPacket (socket.js:455)
    at XHR.<anonymous> (socket.js:278)
    at XHR.Emitter.emit (index.js:133)
    at XHR.Transport.onPacket (transport.js:149)
    at callback (polling.js:144)
    at Object.exports.decodePayload (browser.js:384)
    at XHR.Polling.onData (polling.js:148)
    at Request.<anonymous> (polling-xhr.js:128)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (index.js:133)
    at Request.onData (polling-xhr.js:302)
```

Please, any solution?

Comment: Are you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me in my react native application:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

componentDidMount() {
   const socket = io.connect(url);
   socket.on('message', (data) => {});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure socket server working properly? Did you check it on web?

Comment: can you tell me how to connect using parameters like port and is there some path i need to add in connect.

Comment: i am getting this kind of error .  error:server error in console